# How to activate diff-mode from command line?

Tags: major-mode, git, start-up, diff, command-line-arguments

Git's editor config is set to launch emacs in *no-window mode* and to execute lisp function `diff-mode`:

```
git config --global core.editor "emacs -nw -f diff-mode"
```

However, when I execute `git commit -v` to edit a commit message (the `-v` flag provides the diff to the editor), `diff-mode` is not activated:

[image]

Manually activating the mode by executing the function (<kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> `diff-mode`) *does* work at this point:

[image]

Why does the mode not get activated when I supply `-f diff-mode` on the command line?

Comment: Of course, if your setup works for you, that's great. But! If you're using both emacs and git, I would very much suggest that you try out the excellent package `magit`: https://magit.vc/

Comment: @MTS I finally got around to testing magit out in my workflow, due to your comment. It has completely replaced my need for git outside of emacs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line arguments are processed in-order.  So your `-f diff-mode` will put into `diff-mode` whichever buffer happens to be current right after Emacs has started (most likely it will be the `*scratch*` buffer).  The next argument will probbaly look like `/.../COMMIT_EDITMSG` and will cause Emacs to load that file into some new buffer using some other major mode, determined by `auto-mode-alist`.

So your better option is probably to add to your `~/.emacs` a rule

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" . diff-mode))
```

where `/COMMIT_EDITMSG\'` is a regexp which recognizes specifically the name of the temp files used by `git commit`.